# Bukkit DefaultCommands Permissions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I'm starting up a new Minecraft server.  I was advised to use Bukkit and to use the DefaultCommands plugin to add functionality.  However, upon installation of DefaultCommands, nobody but ops could pick up items...but they had every other permission (set the time, give people items, etc.).  This was a straight-out-of-the-box CraftBukkit install into which I then put the latest DefaultCommands plugin.

I tried mucking around with the permissions file, but it is unclear whether or not I need a special plugin for that, and it is even more unclear as to how I would create permissions that would play nice with DefaultCommands.  The documentation seems half-baked and very out of date.

A quick google search turned up several people asking the same question on the Bukkit forums with no answer; I have confidence that this community might be able to actually give me an answer.

Is there a simple way to make it so that ops/admins of some sort have all the DC permissions and normal (default) users have all the normal, default Minecraft commands (including picking up items...) and nothing more?

Comment: Also, I saw that Essentials might be able to do all that DefaultCommands claims to do, except it might actually work.  Is this a good idea?

Comment: Essentials is a great plugin – I suggest using it. (I've heard of DefaultCommands but have never tried it out myself.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, your best bet here is to use Essentials' GroupManager. It's simple to set up, gives OPs all available commands and lets normal users play with basic permissions. All you have to do is download the Essentials Suite from [here](http://ess.khhq.net/wiki/Downloads), paste the Jar files into your plugins directory and start the server to let it generate the default files.

Then, open `plugins/GroupManager/Worlds/World/Groups.yml` with your favourite text editor and tweak it a little. By default, new players will be added to the `default` group, which has no building permissions. If you change `build: false` to `build: true` under the `info` section, they'll be able to place and destroy blocks, and use a very basic set of commands.

```
groups:
  Default:
    default: true
    permissions:
    - essentials.help
    - essentials.helpop
    - essentials.list
    - essentials.motd
    - essentials.rules
    - essentials.spawn
    inheritance: []
    info:
      prefix: '&e'
      build: false
      suffix: ''

  ...
```

If you want to give your users some more freedom, change `default: false` to `default: true` for the `Builder` group. You can also remove some commands you don't want them to have while still conserving the other ones, such as `essentials.kit` and `essentials.kit.tools`. You can also change the group of the already existing users editing `plugins/GroupManager/Worlds/World/Users.yml`.

For more advanced Permission management, I'd recommend [Permissions 3.x](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/inactive-admn-dev-permissions-3-1-6-the-plugin-of-tomorrow-935.18430/) before DefaultCommands.

**Edit:** Here's a really useful command reference for GroupManager:
[forums.fragnet.net/minecraft/588-essentials-command-reference.html](http://forums.fragnet.net/minecraft/588-essentials-command-reference.html)

Comment: I'm using Essentials for a bunch of other things (basics, XMPP, spawn, etc) so this might be something I will do.  Thansk for the explanations.

Also: is that command reference better than Essentials' own? http://ess.khhq.net/wiki/Command_Reference

Comment: They're basically the same thing, but I find that one to be better organized if you just want to browse through the available commands. Also note that the [GroupManager in-game commands](http://ess.khhq.net/wiki/Group_Manager/Commands) aren't included either of those.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set a permissions file. Bukkit now have one in the root "permissions.yml"

Without that, only ops will be able to use DefaultCommands

Try this website http://www.wi-alliance.com/yamlhelper/

It's will help you create the permissions needed.

Try this in the "permissions.yml" file :

```
---
plugin: 
  permissions: 
    system: 'default'
    copies: ''
groups: 
  Admins: 
    default: false
    info: 
      prefix: '&normal'
      suffix: '§multiplay'
      build: true
    inheritance: ''
    permissions: 
      - '*'
  Default: 
    default: true
    info: 
      prefix: ''
      suffix: ''
      build: true
    inheritance: ''
    permissions: 
      - 'dc.do.<world>'
users: ''
```

change the "world" for the name of your world. Tell me if it worked.

Comment: Will this make ops automatically Admins?

Comment: I think by default, ops have all commands

Answer (score 0):

Warface is mostly correct, but just putting the Permissions in the permissions.yml will *not work*. Permissions.yml is not very useful at the moment, it's really just for permission aliases. Instead, you'll need a Permissions plugin, preferably PermissionsBukkit. You can find PermissionsBukkit on the [forums](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/admn-dev-permissionsbukkit-v1-1-official-default-groups-plugin-1000.26785/) or on [BukkitDev](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/permbukkit/).

Then, you'll need to set up the PermissionsBukkit config.yml. The places I liked give information on how to set up a basic Permissions configuration file. Finally, you'll need to actually assign the Permissions. The permissions nodes can be found [here](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Vanilla_permissions).

Here's a sample configuration file:

```
users:
    SomeUser:
    permissions:
        permissions.example: true
    groups:
    - admin
groups:
    default:
        permissions:
            permissions.build: false
    admin:
        permissions:
            permissions.*: true
        inheritance:
        - user
    user:
        permissions:
            permissions.build: true
        worlds:
            creative:
                coolplugin.item: true
        inheritance:
        - default
messages:
    build: '&cYou do not have permission to build here.'
```

You could add the permission `craftbukkit.command.time: true` to a group, for example, to allow that group to use the `/time` command.